# How do I create random game objects at runtime in Unity (2D) using C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting

I'm a beginner with no experience with Unity whatsoever. I have been reading tutorials and watching videos but can't seem to find what I'm looking for.

How do I create a 3x3 grid with random objects that changes every few seconds?

For example:

[Click this to see what the grid looks like and how it should look after a few seconds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsIG6.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Make a public variable and assign the object (a prefab from the project panel) you want to create to it in the inspector (after dragging the script onto an object)
e.g.
     `public GameObject variable_name`

2)Continue doing that for all the different objects you are using (if you have a large amount I would recommend using a list)

3)Create an iterative structure e.g. a for loop that is called every say 2 seconds which using a random number generator (between 1 and 9 for all your squares) e.g.
    `Random rnd = new Random();
    int square_position = rnd.Next(1, 9);`

4)Generate the object at the location using the function `Instantiate()`
e.g.
    `Instantiate(GameObect_variable_name)`
    and use the transform function to move it to the correct position

For further reading I recommend:

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CreateDestroyObjects.html
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html

Answer (score 1):

make an array of transforms from empty gameobject and place them in your plane (it can be a cube that you look at it from top) then use `Coroutine` to call a method every X seconds and for randomization you can use `Fisher Yates shuffle` to randomize the order in your spawn points and then assign them to your game objects

```
public class game{
     public GameObject[] points;
      public GameObject[] objs;

      void Start()
     {
         StartCoroutine(YourFunctionName());
     }
     IEnumerator YourFunctionName()
     {
         while(true)
         {
             randomPlacer();
             yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
         }
     }



    void randomPlacer()
    {
       RandomizeArray();
       //assign all  new positions to your objects
    }

    public void RandomizeArray(GameObject[] arr)
    {
        for (var i = arr.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            var r = Random.Range(0,i);
            var tmp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[r];
            arr[r] = tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful. Especially the Coroutine thing. :)